# How to know the class for an Array item object in typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to ask by the type or class required to add an item in an Array using typescript, I tried this.

I wan't to build a loop to build buttons to add an element to arrays attributes whose extends from a parent common class example, GenericItem

```
Class Item extends GenericItem

End
```

The Main Class

```
Class mainClass

   items: Array<Item>(); 
   ...
   // Many of arrays 
End
```

Iterating the arrays and create buttons

```
// Loop each of  GenericItem Arrays

let add_btn = document.createElement('button');
add_btn.onclick = (e) => { 
                    // Add an object item to array using the correct class
                }
// end loop
```

Comment: This doesn't appear to be TypeScript code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Add an object item to array using the correct class

You cannot access the `generic` parameters in *variable declaration space*. They only exist in the *type declaration space*. This is because TypeScript types are only there at compile time and purely for compile time checking.

## More

Declaration spaces : https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/project/declarationspaces.html

Why TypeScript (why types don't exist at runtime): https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/why-typescript.html